# Kentico search results showing raw macros

Tags: kentico

I have a table with column headers coming from localization keys. The table code is in an Editable Text webpart. Unfortunatly, the macro is showing in search results. is there a way to avoid this, or limit the smart search webpart? Worst case is i drop the localization implementation.

Here's my code snippet:

```html
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th scope="col">{$kff.Generic-Name$}</th>
   <th class="type" scope="col">{$kff.Generic-Type$}</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

So those macros are page content. You can control what you're showing in search result changing appropriate transformation. Also you might try to go to the appropriate page type search fields and change  Content field.

Comment: There are page content, on a cms.page type. I think the reason is how the index works. It index the DB, which contains code, but that code isn't processed until render time. If that makes sense.

What I've done is restrict the character count on the smart search transformation. It hides the issue rather than solve it. Ideally I'd like to keep the resource keys, but it's not a show stopper.

Comment: @MarkHandy could you please make sure Disable Macro is not checked in search results web part settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `CMS.MacroEngine.MacroResolver.Resolve(string contentResult)` method within your smart search transformation to get those macros resolved into text (or resource strings).